# Remove nested quotations in JSON value

Tags: android, json, regex, kotlin, serialization

I'm parsing a list of objects from some API via kotlinx.serialization. 'description' value in some cases can have nested quotations like this:

```json
{
    "key": "some "awesome" value"
}
```

In the end, this causes JsonDecodingException and i can't parse content. How to remove nested quotations or something else? I don't have ability to edit API.

I was tried to use regular expressions but it didn't worked. The quotes haven't gone anywhere.

What I tried to use:

```
/([^:]+:")(.*)"(.*"})/g
```

```
replace("\"\"", "\"")
```

```
replace("(\"(?:[^\"]|\\\\\")*\")\"", "$1");
```

Comment: In JSON, a non-key string is always followed by a comma or a closing bracket. If one is followed by neither, then the last quote is a nested one.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to find nested quotes by whitespaces around. It's not ideal answer but it's solving my issue.

```
private fun fixNestedQuotes(str: String): String {
    val indexesToRemove = str.indices.filterIndexed { index, _ ->
        (index > 0 && index < str.lastIndex && str[index] == '\"' && str[index - 1].isWhitespace()) ||
                (index > 0 && index < str.lastIndex - 1 && str[index] == '\"' && str[index + 1].isWhitespace())
    }

    return str.filterIndexed{index, _ -> !indexesToRemove.contains(index)}
}
```